# Android mediplayer code with toggle button doesn't work

Tags: android, media-player, togglebutton

I've got mp3's in res/raw folder.
In xml file I got 2 toggle button whose ID's togg1 and togg2. And with this main class i try to run. It works but when i click toggle buttons it doesn't play and song

```
package com.disembodiedtech.funny.sounds;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class FunnySounds extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ToggleButton togg1;
ToggleButton togg2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_funny_sounds);

        togg1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togg1);
        togg2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togg2);
        mbaby = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.baby);
        mband = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.band);
        togg1.setOnClickListener(this);
        togg2.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void OnClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.togg1:
            if(togg1.isChecked()) {
                mbaby.start();
                mbaby.setLooping(true);
            }
            else
                mbaby.pause();
            break;

        case R.id.togg2:
            if(togg2.isChecked()) {
                mband.start();
                mband.setLooping(true);
            }
            else
                mband.pause();
            break;
            }
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are not Overriding `onClick` method of `OnClickListener` .change

```
public void OnClick(View v) {
//...your code here..
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    //...your code here..
}
```